# django query for foreign fields

Tags: django

i am relatively new in django,
i have following model definded,

```
class Project(models.Model):
    offer_header = models.ForeignKey(
    'offers.OfferHeader',
    verbose_name=_('Offer Header'),
    help_text=_('From which offer this project started'),
)

class OfferLine(models.Model):
    offer_header = models.ForeignKey(
    OfferHeader,
    verbose_name=_('Offer Header'),
)
```

say, we have 5 offer lines under the certain offer header.

now from `project` object, how can i get those offer line of that offer header,is django provide any query for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a related_name for reverse relation (for ease of access):

```
class OfferLine(models.Model):
    offer_header = models.ForeignKey(
        OfferHeader,
        verbose_name=_('Offer Header'),
        related_name='lines'
    )
```

Then access related objects from a `project` like so:

```
project.offer_header.lines.all() 
# This will give you all offer lines for that offer header
```

You'll get a queryset of offer lines for that project's offer header. If you need specific ones and if you have the constraints for it, then you can also filter the results and get the ones you want:

```
project.offer_header.lines.filter(...)
```

More info at Django docs [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).